# In the expression "Elevator up" is "up" a preposition or an adverb?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs

I know that in this example: is your house up or down the avenue?
"up" is a preposition. But is it the same in "elevator up"? it looks different

Comment: Can you give us more context.  Is "elevator up" part of a sentence?

Comment: It is a dialogue: - Elevator up! -Fifth floor, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an adverb. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/up) (definition 1.5) has:

> [*as exclamation*] Used as a command to a soldier or an animal to stand up
> and be ready to move or attack.

But in your sentence I think it's a brusque imperative:  an abbreviated form of "Go up!"

Comment: It depends on context, like who's saying it, but I would interpret "Elevator up!" as meaning "This elevator is going up."